# Java apps slow startup when connected to network

Tags: linux, networking, java

I'm using Arch Linux with kernel 3.0 and brcmsmac to manage my wireless card. My desktop environment is KDE 4.7 and I use networkmanager to handle network. Recently I've been affected by a weird problem wherein whenever I'm connected to a network Java apps such as jEdit take ~30 seconds longer to start but behave normal once started. What could it be due to and how can I fix it?

EDIT:The problem occurs both with Oracle's JRE and OpenJDK, both versions 1.7. I'm behind a HTTP proxy, if that makes a difference.

EDIT:I've discovered the cause of this problem. My /etc/hosts file had the wrong host name in it. After correcting this to my hostname, everything is fine. I realized it was due to DNS   thanks to bahamat's excellent answer. I still don't understand why exactly only Java apps were affected but it is fixed anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking [here](http://www.jedit.org/FAQ/problems.html#id452218)?

> **Q:** Why is jEdit so slow to start up?
>
> **A:** Some plugins require a lot of setup - chances are if you disable one, you will be able to determine the culprit. jEdit normally starts up quite quickly without plugins
>
> 1. To go the Utilities menu and select Activity Log.
> 2. Scroll to the area where you see lines like “[notice] JARClassLoader: Starting plugin XXX”.

Your symptoms sound like a DNS timeout though. On Debian sun-java-jre depends on avahi (which is used for mDNS). Perhaps you have a plugin that's trying to do a DNS lookup that's timing out.

Comment: Thanks! But it cant be that because when I'm disconnected from the net, jedit starts within 5 seconds. Its only that when I'm connected it takes ~45 seconds to start. I'll check it anyway

Comment: Added some more info for you.

Comment: I checked the activity log. Nothing seems to take more than about 100ms. BTW, I tried out Netbeans, which also has a similar extra delay of ~45 secs more if I'm online compared to when I'm offline. How can I be sure if it is a DNS issue and what can I do to resolve it if so?